# Entity Framework Core: Cannot update identity column 'Id'

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I found related question but my issue seems to be different.

Running the following code:

```
var dbitem = context.MyDatabaseItems.Single(p => p.Id == someId);
context.Update(dbitem);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Results in **"Cannot update identity column 'Id'"**. Table behind is a bit special. "Id" is NOT the primary key for different reasons. Primary key consists of combination of other fields. No matter what I do: detaching, reattaching etc etc the existing item I am unable to save the entity even if I do not change it (see the code).

However this Id is unique and auto generated.

The builder is the following:

```
builder.Property(p => p.Id)
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

builder.HasKey(p => new { p.BusinessDay, p.ClientId, p.Version });
```

BusinessDay is dateTime, CLientId and Version are integers.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 12):

There are two metadata properties which control the update behavior called `BeforeSaveBehavior` and `AfterSaveBehavior`.

For auto generated *keys* the later is assumed to be `Ignore`, i.e. never update. For non key auto generated properties it must be configured explicitly (note that there is no fluent API for that so far, so you have to use the metadata API directly), e.g.

```cs
// First define the new key
builder.HasKey(p => new { p.BusinessDay, p.ClientId, p.Version });

// Then configure the auto generated column
// This (especially the `SetAfterUpdateBehavior` call) must be after 
// unassociating the property as a PK, otherwise you'll get an exception
builder.Property(p => p.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // <--
```

This does not change the database schema (model), hence no migration is needed. Just the EF Core update entity behavior.

Comment: works for me, thanks Ivan. But is this still necessary in EF7? Seems like this was a workaround for back then...

Comment: @Sean Is it still necessary - don't know, haven't checked it since then, and they of course  modify their code. From the other side, explicit configuration (even if redundant), never hurts :) And Non PK Identity columns should be very rare.